# Adding a sidebar and footer to a table

Tags: html, css

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
+++++++++++
+    +    +
+ TD + TD +
+    +    +
+++++++++++
+    +    +
+ TD + TD +
+    +    +
+++++++++++
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to add a sidebar:

```
++++++++++++++++
+    +    + S  +
+ TD + TD + I  +
+    +    + D  +
+++++++++++ E  +
+    +    + B  +
+ TD + TD + A  +
+    +    + R  +
++++++++++++++++
```

Or a footer

```
++++++++++++++++
+    +    + S  +
+ TD + TD + I  +
+    +    + D  +
+++++++++++ E  +
+    +    + B  +
+ TD + TD + A  +
+    +    + R  +
++++++++++++++++
+         +
+ FOOTER  +
+         +
+++++++++++
```

So, aside from my terrible ASCII skills, this is the HTML that I mentioned in the first model:

```
<!-- Flatly, a baller theme, I use it in almost all projects -->
<link href = "https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid #000 1px !important;
}
```

Giving a result you can see at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tv5od4fg/2/) fiddle.

Now, if you're wondering why I would possibly need to make this, its for a little experiment I'm making, which will allow you to add to the table by pressing the sidebar and footer to extend the table by rows and columns. I'm attempting to make the footer and sidebar the same height and width as the table. (As shown in model 3)

Comment: try colspan=n and rowspan=n

Comment: Actually pretty good ASCII skills ;)

Comment: Aww thanks :D. My ASCII is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (i.e. this number of rows and colums, 2x2), you could do it by adding additional cells/columns/rows like below. This will add the "sidebar"  as a new column over the complete height and the "footer" as a new row over 2 columns.

```css
td { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>test content</td>
        <td>test content</td>
        <td rowspan=3>"sidebar"</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test content</td>
        <td>test content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>"footer"</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Not quite what I was looking for, but it does explain what colspan and rowspan are. I will make sure to use those attributes later in my programming!

Answer (score 0):

Pls check

**[JSFIDDLE - Using Table](https://jsfiddle.net/tv5od4fg/8/)**

**[JSFIDDLE- Using Div](https://jsfiddle.net/tv5od4fg/9/)**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
    <td rowspan='4'> sidebar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan='2'>Footer</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

---

**Using DIV**

```
<div id="header">
  This is header

</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <p>
      main content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    side bar
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  This is my footer
</div>
```

---

```
#header,
#footer,
#content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 78%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.right-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! But the idea was that was the footer and sidebar would auto adjust. Also, the footer is a bit too large (adjusted to my needs) and seems like a fair solution. Thanks for the quick answer, it works well!

Comment: Its better if you use DIV this also help to create responsive Layout, also  have added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid #000 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href = "https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
2) 
<table>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
3) 
<table>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Try It Once

Comment: Great answer, it fits all three models :D

Comment: @captain-crunch@ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid #000 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Flatly, a baller theme, I use it in almost all projects -->
<link href = "https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is jsfiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tv5od4fg/6/)